# Get a cell value using a filter on another cell value

Tags: r

I have following data.table.

```
          Genre  PS4 X360
 1:       Action 0.71 0.75
 2:    Adventure 0.25 0.32
 3:     Fighting 0.47 0.58
 4:         Misc 0.49 0.73
 5:     Platform 0.64 0.47
 6:       Puzzle 0.02 0.12
 7:       Racing 0.68 0.63
 8: Role-Playing 0.55 0.95
 9:      Shooter 2.22 1.37
10:   Simulation 0.15 0.36
11:       Sports 1.16 0.63
12:     Strategy 0.08 0.36
13:        (all) 0.83 0.77
```

I want to get the `Genre` value where `PS4` gets its maximum value. So expected value is **Shooter**.

I could get the maximum value of `PS4` using `dt[,max(PS4)]`. How can I use this result to get the corresponding value of the column "`Genre`"

Comment: `dt$Genre[which(dt$PS4 == max(dt$PS4))]`?

Comment: @JohnColeman It gives me an error `Error in which(dt$PS4) : argument to 'which' is not logical`

Comment: There was a typo in my initial comment. Try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `which()`:

```
> dt$Genre[which(dt$PS4 == max(dt$PS4))]
[1] Shooter
13 Levels: (all) Action Adventure Fighting Misc Platform Puzzle ... Strategy
```

Alternatively (and even simpler), just use logical subsetting:

```
> dt$Genre[dt$PS4 == max(dt$PS4)]
[1] Shooter
13 Levels: (all) Action Adventure Fighting Misc Platform Puzzle ... Strategy
```